# How to change sliding tab strip animation duration for TabLayout?

Tags: java, android, xml

The `SlidingTabStrip` `ANIMATION_DURATION` is set to `300` in `TabLayout.java`. 
Is there a way/method used to customise the animation duration either in `xml` or programatically in `java`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [`static final`](https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_support/blob/master/design/src/android/support/design/widget/TabLayout.java#L158) field, so it cannot be changed from neither `xml` nor Java.

The only way you *may* succeed it is [using reflection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3301720/1083957).